# Invalid reference from destroy provisioner

Tags: terraform

I'm getting the following Error: Invalid reference from destroy provisioner. It's not clear to me why this error is occurring.

Destroy-time provisioners and their connection configurations may only
reference attributes of the related resource, via 'self', 'count.index', or
'each.key'.

References to other resources during the destroy phase can cause dependency
cycles and interact poorly with create_before_destroy.

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when = destroy
    inline = [
      "java -jar /home/ec2-user/jenkins-cli.jar -auth @/home/ec2-user/jenkins_auth -s http://${aws_instance.jenkins-master.private_ip}:8080 delete-node ${self.private_ip}"
    ]
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
      host        = self.public_ip
    }
  }


Error: Invalid reference from destroy provisioner

  on instances.tf line 67, in resource "aws_instance" "jenkins-worker-oregon":
  67:     inline = [
  68:       "java -jar /home/ec2-user/jenkins-cli.jar -auth @/home/ec2-user/jenkins_auth -s http://${aws_instance.jenkins-master.private_ip}:8080 delete-node ${self.private_ip}"
  69:     ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and the solution in my case has been to use a null_resource that gets triggered when a specific value has changed.

In your case, a solution could be the following:

```
resource "null_resource" "register-to-master" {
  triggers = {
    jenkins-master-ip = aws_instance.jenkins-master.private_ip
    private_ip = some_value
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when = destroy
    inline = [
      "java -jar /home/ec2-user/jenkins-cli.jar -auth @/home/ec2-user/jenkins_auth -s http://${self.triggers.jenkins-master-ip}:8080 delete-node ${self.triggers.private_ip}"
    ]
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
      host        = self.triggers.public_ip
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when = create
    inline = [ "echo 'create step'" ]
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
      host        = self.triggers.public_ip
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can only reference attributes of the related resource, then the "invalid reference" is presumably the reference to `aws_instance.jenkins-master.private_ip` in the inline command, which is referring to something outside the related resource.

Comment: Can you suggest how I could implement it differently?

Comment: Nothing solid springs to mind. You may need to pin your Terraform version to v12 (where I think this should work) until you can figure out an alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

you can use the tags to have the master private IP and use self.tags like this

```
tags = {
  Name = "put_a_nice_name_or_some_thing_here" #change_this
  Master_Private_IP = aws_instance.jenkins-master.private_ip
}
```

in the provisioner block:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    when = destroy
    inline = [
      "java -jar /home/ec2-user/jenkins-cli.jar -auth @/home/ec2-user/jenkins_auth -s http://${self.tags.Master_Private_IP}:8080 delete-node ${self.private_ip}"
    ]
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"
      private_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa")
      host        = self.public_ip
    }
  }
```